# Button Sizing Mishaped

Tags: java, button, jpanel

I am working on a program and I am having an issue with three of my buttons. 
Here is the code for them:

```
panel.add(clearButton, c);
c.gridwidth = 1;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 4;
c.weighty = 1.0;

panel.add(addButton);
c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
c.gridx = 2;
c.gridy = 4;
c.weightx = 1.00;

panel.add(calcButton);
c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
c.gridx = 2;
c.gridy = 4;
c.weightx = 1.00;
```

For some reason when the program runs, the clearbutton is not the same as the addButton and calcButton.

Can anyone help me on this? Here is the reference I am using: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html

Please tell me if you need more info!

Comment: What is `c`? Why aren't you using one when you add `addButton` and `calcButton`?

Comment: Thanks. It seems I dont have enough rep to answer my own question. I added  panel.add(addButton, c); and  panel.add(calcButton, c); and it was fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `c`? Why aren't you using one when you add `addButton` and `calcButton`?

Also, you don't need to keep setting its fields to the same values.